# Why won't Hibernate execute query

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using a hibernate tutorial to help me use Hibernate in a Java servlet to read in a set of SFTP connection details from an Oracle database to make them configurable.  The Oracle database table is named SFTP_CREDS.  I have a class that sets up the session etc and then the first line of code below runs but then fails on the second line stating the message "could not execute query".  Why is this happening?  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code that sets up the query and then fails on the second line;

```
Query query = hibernateSession.createQuery("FROM SFTPCreds");
java.util.List list = query.list();
```

This is the SFTPCreds class;

```
package the.package.name;

public class SFTPCreds {

   private String sftp_host;
   private int sftp_port;
   private String sftp_username;
   private String sftp_password;
   private String sftp_fingerprint;
   private String sftp_hostkey;
   private String sftp_file;

     public String getSftp_host() {
        return sftp_host;
     }
     public void setSftp_host(String sftp_host) {
         this.sftp_host = sftp_host;
     }

     public int getSftp_port() {
         return sftp_port;
     }
     public void setSftp_port(int sftp_port) {
         this.sftp_port = sftp_port;
     }

     public String getSftp_username() {
         return sftp_username;
     }
     public void setSftp_username(String sftp_username) {
         this.sftp_username = sftp_username;
     }

     public String getSftp_password() {
        return sftp_password;
     }
     public void setSftp_password(String sftp_password) {
        this.sftp_password = sftp_password;
     }

     public String getSftp_fingerprint() {
        return sftp_fingerprint;
     }
     public void setSftp_fingerprint(String sftp_fingerprint) {
        this.sftp_fingerprint = sftp_fingerprint;
     }

     public String getSftp_hostkey() {
         return sftp_hostkey;
     }
     public void setSftp_hostkey(String sftp_hostkey) {
         this.sftp_hostkey = sftp_hostkey;
     }

     public String getSftp_file() {
        return sftp_file;
     }
     public void setSftp_file(String sftp_file) {
         this.sftp_file = sftp_file;
     }

}
```

This is the mapping file sftpcreds.hbm.xml which is listed in a hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="the.package.name">
  <class name="SFTPCreds" table="SFTP_CREDS">
    <id column="SFTP_HOST" name="sftp_host">
          <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property column="SFTP_PORT" generated="never" lazy="false" 
           name="sftp_port" />
    <property column="SFTP_USERNAME" generated="never" lazy="false" 
           name="sftp_username" />
    <property column="SFTP_PASSWORD" generated="never" lazy="false" 
           name="sftp_password" />
    <property column="SFTP_FINGERPRINT" generated="never" lazy="false" 
           name="sftp_fingerprint" />
    <property column="SFTP_HOSTKEY" generated="never" lazy="false" 
          name="sftp_hostkey" />
    <property column="SFTP_FILE" generated="never" lazy="false" 
         name="sftp_file" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here are some details of the console output, I have just noticed that the second set of messages says table or view does not exist.  The table indeed exists but maybe I have a configuration wrong somewhere

```
 org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
       at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:90)
       at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2235)
    . many
    . more 
    . lines
    .
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
       at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
       at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:289)
```

Lastly, I am not using direct JDBC connections to the data source I am using Java Naming Directory Interface (JNDI) and declaring the connections in Tomcat's global conf.xml and a hibernate.cfg.xml points to the JNDI data source.  Why is this not working please?

Comment: Hibernate is not able to access the table, so directly access the DB and see if the table is present or not. If it is there then try to test with simple JDBC code and see if there are any restrictions in accessing your DB tables.

Comment: Are you sure `SFTP_CREDS` exits in your database?

Comment: @Chaitanya. Thanks for editing my question, I actually thought I had formated the console output as code.  I will look into trying a JDBC connection

Comment: @DarshanLila Yes the SFTP_CREDS exists but I have this a little further.  I am using a JNDI connection setup and it seems to not recognise the JNDI data source.  I have a JNDI entry for projectName which works fine and a JNDI entry for projectNameTest which also previously worked fine, but while trying to amend the Train application (to get the configuration working) it states that it cannot find projectNameTest data source

Comment: @Chaitanya See my update to Darshan Lila.  For some reason it cannot see the JNDI data source

Comment: @user2696089, I am confused now, what is `projectName`, what is `projectNameTest` and what is `Train application`? No where in your post you have mentioned about them and also there is nothing called JNDI in your post.

Comment: @Chaitanya I apologise Chaitanya the last message was very vague and I should not have just used projectName.  The project name is financeTrans (Finance Transfer) and this is the name of the instance of the Java servlet created in Eclipse which connects to the Live database but we also have a Test instance named financeTransTest which connects to the Training\Test database.  I have updated the post to mention using JNDI